# Extract substring from the first letter

Tags: c#, string

I need to extract substring from string but starting with the first letter

**example** :

```
string s1 = "12 x 13 ABC 12@ 15.8" substring =  ABC 12@ 15.8
string s2 = "25 x 32 FER @23.8" substring =  FER @23.8
```

I tried the index of for the letter A or F but it didn't work

thanks

Comment: mind that `x` in your case is also a letter

Comment: Are all your strings the same "NN x NN AAA some text" format? (Two digits, a space and an x and a space, followed by letters and other stuff.) If so, you can use `Substring(s1, 9)`. If not, make it more clear what types of data you need to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (in case you use a non-letter character instead of `x`)

```
string SubstringThis(string input)
{
  return new string(input.SkipWhile(c => !char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray());
}
```

Comment: This will give substring "x 13 ABC 12@ 15.8" and not "ABC 12@ 15.8". Isnt it?

Comment: I think you meant `char.IsLetter`.

Comment: Ok then replace `!char.IsLetter(c)` with `!char.IsLetter(c) || c =='x'`

Comment: @Kupiakos Thanks! Fixed it.

Comment: @bashis thanks it's working: `return new string(input.SkipWhile(c => !char.IsLetter(c) || c == 'x' || c=='X').ToArray());`

Answer (score 0):

Simple utility function:

```
string SubstringFromFirstLetter(string s)
{
    for (int i=0; i < s.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (char.IsLetter(s[i]))
        {
            return s.Substring(i);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Keep in mind that `x` is a letter. Do you want it to match only capitalized letters?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string GetSubstringStartingWithFirstAlphaCharacter(this string toEvaluate)
        {
            const string pattern = "([a-zA-Z])(.+)";

            var regex = new Regex(pattern);

            return regex.Match(toEvaluate).Value;
        }
```

Comment: Best Method name ever :P

Comment: Shout out to Robert C. Martin and his book "Clean Code." You know exactly what you're getting when you call that bad boy.